# how to include jar file for oozie

Tags: sqoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to a sqoop action in oozie, but mysql-connector-java.jar is not present in /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop, because of no permission I am not able to add the jar as of now,
Is there any way or workaround to include mysql-connector-java.jar in workflow.xml

I have placed the jar in sqoop apps / lib directory, but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the Hadoop administrator should keep all the common library in Hadoop distribution to make the usage more efficient, if not, give a try to the following -jarfile option

```
sqoop import \
    -libjars /file/location/path/mysql-connector-java.jar \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:3306/retail_db \
    --username root \
    --password xyzpwd \
    --table order_items \
    --target-dir /user/cloudera/landing_zone/sqoop_import/order_items
```

as per [sqoop documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html):

-libjars     specify a comma separated jar files to include in the classpath. The -files, -libjars, and -archives arguments are not typically used with Sqoop, but they are included as part of Hadoop’s internal argument-parsing system.